# Configuring several injections in Guice

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

In Guice, I have a class "Panel" and a class "Controller". Both are interrelated. Controller has 3 subclasses (say A, B and C). I would like to offer the programmers an easy way to get an instance of Panel with one of the 3 Controllers injected, depending on their needs. 
For instance, in a specific point of code, a programmer may want to get an instance of the Panel with a ControllerA injected, but in a different place he might need the Panel with a ControllerB.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a binding annotation to let the user specify which one they wanted:
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations

You'd create the annotations like this:

```
import com.google.inject.BindingAnnotation;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;

@BindingAnnotation @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface WithClassA{}
@BindingAnnotation @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface WithClassB{}
...
```

Then your user's constructor looks like

```
@Inject
public MyConstructor(@WithClassA Panel thePanel) {...}
```

Then when you do the binding, you would use .annotatedWith:

```
bind(Panel.class)
    .annotatedWith(WithClassA.class)
    .toProvider(ProviderThatReturnsPanelConstructedWithA.class);
bind(Panel.class)
    .annotatedWith(WithClassB.class)
    .toProvider(ProviderThatReturnsPanelConstructedWithB.class);
```

Just in case, here's the documentation on how to set up providers: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, creating one annotation and one provider for each controller looks like a bit overkill, IMO. My question shows a simplified scenario, but the real project involves a refactoring of an application with hundred of panels and controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a possible solution: Guice allows you to bind to a provider instance, not only a class. Thus you can create just one provider with a constructor with one argument, and bind it like so:

> bind(Panel.class).annotatedWith(WithClassA.class).toProvider(new MyProvider("a"))

The constructor's argument type could be any other like i.e. an enum or even an annotation, passing in the same WithClassA.class.

This is a nice way to save providers. The drawback is that you won't have dependency injection in your provider, but this is something I can live without, in this scenario.